# Filter results from Mongoose array and populate subfield of objectId's

Tags: javascript, arrays, mongodb, mongoose

I have a Mongoose schema that I've simplified a bit for the question:

```
const userSchema = Schema({
    email: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    profiles: [{
        profileId: {
            type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: 'Profile',
            required: true
        },
        accessLevel: {
            type: Number,
            required: true
        }
    }],  
})
```

And I'm trying to fetch the name field from the Profile Mongoose object while fitering by accessLevel: something like

```
const profileNames = req.user.profiles.filter(p =>
    p.accessLevel <= 2
  ).populate('profileId').map(p=>p.name)
```

But obviously this throws an error. How would I go about retrieving this information? Thanks...

Rik

Edit: ok... this seems to work but not ideal:

```
const profiles = req.user.profiles.filter(f =>
    f.accessLevel <= 2
  ).map(

    p => {   
      return Profile.findById(p.profileId)
    }
  )
  Promise.all(profiles).then(
    profiles => {
      profiles = profiles.map(
        p => p.name
      )
//=>Do stuff with profiles here
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay, this seems to work and is reasonable:

```
  const profiles = req.user.profiles.filter(f =>
    f.accessLevel <= 2
  ).map(
    p => p.profileId
  )
  Profile.find({
    "_id": {
      $in: profiles
    }
  }).then(
    profiles => {
      profiles = profiles.map(
        p => p.name)

     //=>Do stuff with profiles here
     })
```